# How to disable PKCanvasView from scrolling when selecting a drawing with lasso and moving it around

Tags: pencilkit

I think the title explains it pretty clearly. I have a `PKCanvasView` which is partially zoomed in, and when I select a part of the drawing with the lasso tool and then move it around with my pencil, the whole view starts shifting around following my pencil.

Tried setting `isScrollEnabled` to `false` but no dice.